# The result set with field name as key and value pairs

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to get the result set of the query as key/value pairs, without extends the JpaRepository.
The following code returns list with just the values  ["Name", "Address","physique@gmail.com"],...

```
@Repository  
public class Coordinateur_dao_Imp{
    public List<Coordinateur> getCoordinateurs() {        
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();  
        Query<Coordinateur> query=currentSession.createNativeQuery("select * from coordinateur c");
        List<Coordinateur> list=query.getResultList();  
    return list;  
    }
```

and

```
@RestController  
public class Controller {
@GetMapping("/api/coordinateur-list")  
        public List<Coordinateur> getCoordinateurs() {  
             return coordinateur_dao.getCoordinateurs();  

        }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of JPA/Hibernate is to map relational database rows to managed objects. If you don't want objects, but want key value pairs, why don't you use JDBC? What is the concrete problem you're trying to solve that couldn't be solved by having a proper object, with named and typed properties?

Comment: I need the keys to use them in the front_end

Comment: Why would you need that? Spring Boot uses Jackson by default, which converts objects to JSON (or XML) natively. So you will have those keys and values in the JSON.

Comment: I tried to get the keys by using  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
      <version>8.5.30</version>
  </dependency>, but It does not work

Comment: Errr, what? Jasper is Tomcat's JSP engine. What does it have to do with your question? Are you asking how to display a list of objects inside a JSP?

Comment: I created a Spring Starter Project using STS, I have a SQL server database; I created coordinateur class with @Entity to mapped with the coordinateur table. I need to get a List of coordinators from the coordinateurs table, but without using the CRUDRepository or JpaRepository Interfaces. I used Postman to send get request but it does not returne json format Key/value

Comment: To represent my result in a json format I add the  tomcat-jasper dependency in the Pom.xml file

Comment: When I extends CRUDRepository or JpaRepository Interfaces, I get the result of the query as key/value as I used the named methode query or @query annotation that uses the HQL. But in above situation I can't; Is it clear?

Comment: tomcat-jasper has nothing to do with JSON. Spring-web depends on Jackson, which is a JSON mapper. So you don't need to add anything to be able to serialize objects as JSON, and certainly not tomcat-jasper. And no, it isn't clear. What happens when you use the above method. Tell what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Your query is a JPQL query, not a SQL query. So you shouldn't use `createNativeQuery()` to create it, but `createQuery()`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, Ok let's forget the tomcat-jasper; when I use the above methode getCoordinateurs in the Coordinateur_dao_Imp I got a list of coordinateur objects , but I got only the values[{"Jhon", Jhon@gmail.com},"Alix", Alix@gmail.com}] without the keys. I need keys and values such as [{nom:"Jhon", email:Jhon@gmail.com}, nom:"Alix", email:Alix@gmail.com}].  I got Error in case of replace createNativeQuery() by the createQuery().

Comment: It's an object. The keys are the names of the properties in the object. You call getName() to get the name, and getEmail() to get the email. And if you return this object from a Rest controller, Jackson will use the properties as keys for the JSON: `{"name": "Jhon", "email"; "Jhon@gmail.com"}`. Java works wilth objects. Java objects are transformed into JSON objects. No need for "key/value pairs".